# how can i solve this while running node server.js in mernstack project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules, mern

D:\suruthi\mernstack\server>node server.js
Server is running on port: 5000
D:\suruthi\mernstack\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:202
callback(new error_1.MongoServerError(document));
^

MongoServerError: bad auth : Authentication failed.
at Connection.onMessage (D:\suruthi\mernstack\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:202:26)
at MessageStream. (D:\suruthi\mernstack\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:61:60)
at MessageStream.emit (node:events:512:28)
at processIncomingData (D:\suruthi\mernstack\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:124:16)
at MessageStream._write (D:\suruthi\mernstack\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:33:9)
at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)
at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:766:22)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:512:28) {
ok: 0,
code: 8000,
codeName: 'AtlasError',
connectionGeneration: 0,
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(2) { 'HandshakeError', 'ResetPool' }
}

Node.js v19.6.0

D:\suruthi\mernstack\server>node server.js

how can i solve this??

Comment: I think you are using an incorrect username or password for your MongoDB user.

Comment: You are not providing enough information, please edit the post to include more context. Otherwise, like @VictorL. said, it could be something as trivial as a wrong password.